# Referenced DLL is not found when running application from VS

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I created a managed VC++ class library, and now I created a new C# console application. I added the DLL from the class library as a reference. Now, when I try to run my program from VS, VS complains that it cannot find the DLL. When I check the output folder `bin\Debug`, however, the DLL is there.

Is there anything I forgot to configure?

Comment: Did you add the reference to the References folder in your C# project?

Comment: Well, then you know it isn't complaining about the DLL you can see.  So it is probably another one, you typically create a C++/CLI project to write a wrapper.  So you also have a dependency on whatever DLL contains that native code.  You'll have to copy it yourself, use a post-build event.  Or ensure that both the C++/CLI project and the C# project generate their build results into the same directory.  YMMV.  If you can't figure it out then use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  You'll see your program searching for the DLL and not finding it.

Comment: I think this is the culprit. I created another class library which has no other dependencies, and another console application to use it, and there it worked. And yes, my DLL is interfacing another one, so I have to copy the dependent one manually. Thanks.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer was in Hans passant's comment: The DLL which could not be loaded referenced another DLL which was not present in the output directory. That's why I got the exception.

I now added a post-build step which copies the DLL to the output directory after a successful build, and voilà, it works.